# Number of Automorphisms of $S_6$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, automorphism-group

Trivial question about counting the number of automorphisms of $S_6$:

I know that for all $n \geq 3$, $Z(S_n)=1$, so Inn$(S_n) \cong S_n$.

I also know that $S_6$ has nontrivial outer homomorphisms, Out$S_n \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Does this mean there are $S_n + \mathbb{Z}_2$ automorphisms in total, since Inn$(S_n)$ and Out$(S_n)$ are disjoint sets? So, other symmetric groups (excluding $S_2$) have $n!$ elements, while $S_6$ has $6! + 2$.

Comment: Times 2........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $\operatorname{Out}(S_6)=\operatorname{Aut}(S_6)/\operatorname{Inn}(S_6)\cong C_2$ and hence
$$
|\operatorname{Aut}(S_6)|=|S_6|\cdot |C_2|=6!\cdot 2.
$$
Here we have used that $|G/N|=\frac{|G|}{|N|}$.

Comment: Is this because we include all compositions in Aut $S_n$? So, for every inner automorphism, we can compose it with one of the outer homomorphisms?

Comment: The outer automorphisms are those ones which are not inner modulo the inner ones, so the quotient group.

Comment: But there are $6!$ inner automorphisms, and $2$ outer automorphisms. So I was asking why  intuitively we are not adding the number of inner and out automophisms

Comment: Well, modulo the inner ones, so times $2$.

Comment: There are $6!$ outer automorphisms, not $2$.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathrm{Out} (S_n) $ is not a group of automorphisms, but is the quotient of the automorphism group by the subgroup of inner automorphisms. Thus 
$$|\mathrm{Out}(S_n) |=|\mathrm{Aut} (S_n) |/|S_n|$$
so you can find the order of the automorphism group this way.

Essentially an outer automorphism is an equivalence class of automorphisms $f(x) $ where $f(x) \sim \sigma f(x) \sigma^{-1}$ for any $\sigma$.

Answer (score 1):

The group $S_6$ has an outer automorphism that is unique up to composition with an inner automorphism. Hence, the group $S_6$ has 1440 automorphisms.